# Room: Use class that extends ArrayList as Entity

Tags: java, android, inheritance, arraylist, android-room

I am making an Android app using the Room Persistence Library. I have a class that `extends` the `ArrayList` class like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "the_table_name")
public class MyDemoClass<E extends AnotherDemoClass> extends ArrayList<E> {

  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
  private String title;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "creationdate")
  private Date creationDate;

  // Other stuff
}
```

I'm trying to add this class, which only allows classes that *extend AnotherDemoClass* to be in it, as an entity to Room but there's a compile-time error occurring, which is:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        _result = new MyDemoClass<E>();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class E
  location: class MyDemoClassDao_Impl
```

I've been trying for more than an hour to fix this issue without any luck.

**EDIT:**
This is my `Dao`:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDemoClassDao {

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  void insert(MyDemoClass<AnotherDemoClass> myDemoClass);

}
```

If your answer could help in any way, please do share it with me!

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please dont give a fragment of your code, show all *relevant* parts. Like the line and context that gives the error.

Comment: Beyond that, you probably don't understand what these generics mean in the first place. So: you should research that topic a bit more ;-)

Comment: Do you really mean that you are trying to put `@Entity` on `MyDemoClass`? If so, what would you expect the SQLite table to look like that corresponds to this class?

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, if you use the code I just gave here, you will be able to reproduce the issue :D

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it seems like Room doesn't accept such classes. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What you expect the SQL table to look like with your structure? You should use a  Object that have a ID plus a List<ObjB> and two tables, one for ObjectA (with ID only on this case) and ObjB that have a ForeignKey for ObjA

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I'd like to use MyDemoClass as a playlist. I'd add Songs to this playlist and save it inside the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to use MyDemoClass as a playlist. I'd add Songs to this playlist and save it inside the database

`MyDemoClass` would be a plain ol' Java object (POJO) and would have fields that correspond to simple properties of a playlist, such as a `String` that would serve as the name that users can provide and see in rosters of playlists. `MyDemoClass` would *not* be a subclass of `ArrayList`.

`Song` would be another POJO and have fields that correspond to simple properties of a song, such as a `String` for its title.

Since a playlist can have multiple songs, and a song can appear in multiple playlists, you would need to create an entity that represents that join, with foreign key relationships back to the playlist and song entities.

The use of foreign key relationships is lightly covered in [the Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#object-relationships). It should be covered in any book that spends significant time on Room. For example, here is [a preview edition of my chapter on M:N relations in Room](https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/mn-relations-in-room) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look into this and accept your answer if it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @CommonsWare, I googled "M:N relations in Room" and found a really good tutorial on it. Recommend it to everyone who is struggling in Room https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a